# How to Delete Current User with UIAlert using Swift with Firebase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

quick question I am trying to give the user the option to delete their account from firebase using swift on Xcode.

I currently have a "Delete" button that leads to a UIAlert that ask if the user is sure they want to delete their account (just in case) like this
[image]

and my code for this action is below

```
//Handles delete current user account (not fnished yet)
@IBAction func deleteAccount(_ sender: Any) {
    createAlert2(title: "Delete Account", message: "Are you sure you want to delete your account? This will permanently erase your account.")
}
```

to this function

```
    func createAlert2 (title:String, message:String){
    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (action) in
        alert2.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (action) in
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

        user?.delete { error in
            if error != nil {
                // An error happened.
            } else {
                // Account deleted.
                print("user deleted")
            }
        }
        let controller2 = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
        self.present(controller2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My goal is to delete the user and send them back to that MenuViewController. But all it seems to do is send the user to that menu view and not actually delete their account on firebase. Any help is appreciated and I always like and check mark answers. Thank you:)

Comment: I would suggest adding print("an error occurred \(errText)" in the *if err* check. As it is, if there's an error you would not know about it.

Comment: I honestly have no Idea how that worked. But now its actually deleting the user just by putting that in. print("error deleting user"). Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 2):

If you print errors or just put few breakpoints after user?.delete, most probably you going to see something like this:

> Optional
>     - some : Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17014 "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request., error_name=ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN}

It means that you need to sign up or re-authenticate again with credentials (email, password) to have the ability to delete your user. You can user code bellow with some improvements(choose your way how to get credentials)

// Latest firebase + swift 4

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
let password = "mypassword from stream - ask for a password from your user"
let email = user?.email


let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)

user?.reauthenticateAndRetrieveData(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
    if let error = error {
        // handle error here
        print(error)
    }else{
        user?.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                // handle your error here
                print(error)
            }else{
                do {
                    // handle your signout smth like: 
                    try Auth.auth().signOut()
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                } catch let logoutError {
                    // handle your error here
                    print(logoutError)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Unfortunately this issue documentation is very poor(especially latest version). Hope you find my answer useful.
Note***: giving your user ability to delete his profile directly it is a very BAD idea (IMHO), better if you send email notification and disable user and invalidate his tokens or UID, it will give you more flexibility in the future.